# Setting shape of RaggedTensor with Known Shape

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow, gradient-descent

I'm working with RaggedTensors to manipulate a dense tensor. Something like this :

```
    out_left = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(input, index)
    
    index = tf.math.logical_not(index)
    out_right = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(input, index)

    reconstruced_tensor = tf.concat([out_left, out_right], axis=-1)

    reconstruced_tensor =  reconstruced_tensor.to_tensor()
```

As you can see, in my example, I'm just splitting my input tensor using RaggedTensors and reconstructing it (I know its useless, but it's just for the sake of simplicity)

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting the following warning:

`IndexedSlices(IndexedSlices(indices=Tensor("gradient_tape/model_14/channel_roll_13/RaggedToTensor/boolean_mask_1/GatherV2:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int32), values=Tensor("gradient_tape/model_14/channel_roll_13/RaggedToTensor/boolean_mask/GatherV2:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=Tensor("gradient_tape/model_14/channel_roll_13/RaggedToTensor/Shape:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32))) to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory. "shape. This may consume a large amount of memory." % value)`

Since I know the shape of the output Tensor, I would have thought Tensorflow would too.  Is there any way I can explicitly specify the shape of the output tensor since Tensorflow doesn't seem to deduce it on its own?

Comment: If your shapes are well known to you then why you just don't use tf.boolean_mask() instead?

Comment: @MohammadAhmed I need to split the tensors into variable length lists before rearranging them. For context, I wrote a cyclical shift function, that shifts each pixel of an RGB image, channel-wise. I can't use `tf.roll` because I need to shift each pixel by a different amount, and `tf.roll` shifts the whole tensor by a single amount, that's why I use RaggedTensors

Answer (score 0):

If you exactly know the shapes of your tensor then try this code... Decorate this function by @tf.function and specify the input shapes and first time it will take some extra time for **tracing** then next time it will be executed very effectively.

```
@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(
    shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32 #Can change the shape according to your inputs
),
                             tf.TensorSpec(
    shape=[None], dtype=tf.bool
)])
def transform(_inputs , _index):
    out_left = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(_inputs, _index)

    _index = tf.math.logical_not(_index)
    out_right = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(_inputs, _index)

    reconstruced_tensor = tf.concat([out_left, out_right], axis=-1)

    return reconstruced_tensor
```

```
#Some dummy inputs
_inputs = tf.range(10)
indices = tf.cast(tf.random.uniform(shape=[10], minval=0, maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32 ), dtype=tf.bool)
```

```
transform(_inputs, indices)
```

Output

````
<tf.Tensor: shape=(10,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 2, 4, 5, 8])>
```
````